# Issue reading text file python

Tags: python

I am new to python and stuck with some issue which could be pretty easy for python expert. I am trying to read text file in python but not getting desired out put using f string.

```
print(f'{lines[0]} {lines[2]}')\n
```

I am getting output in two lines, although I didn't use \n

```
Hello
 I am testing!
```

Expected output:

```
Hello I am testing!
```

Comment: It would seem that either `lines[0]` has a `\n` at the end, or `lines[2]` has a `\n` at the beginning.  Note that you can use `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace (including newlines) from strings.

Comment: Please include how you get `lines`.

Comment: `lines[0]` itself has a newline character at the end.

Comment: Got it guys...typical beginner mistake :D. Strip worked as \n was added by default. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you read a file at end of every line a newline character exists. So if you even print only one line you'll get a blank line after the text. You can solve it by using strip method:

```
print(f'{lines[0].strip()} {lines[2].strip()}')
```

Comment: This answer just copied the idea of [0x5453's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546402/issue-reading-text-file-python#comment121141244_68546402)

Comment: In my defense when I started to write the answer there was no commands to the question. But you're right I was late to submit.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your text file, the text is in different lines, so python interpreted it as a newline. So, it added a new line character `\n`. You just have to strip the character.

```
print(f'{lines[0].strip('\n')} {lines[2].strip('\n')}')
```